# Convert field from Json to int and change it value

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin

I have activity with button "+" and "-"

When I tap "+" count of my products change to +1

And I have price, it parse from json.

I need to convert "price" field to int and  increase price when I tap "+".

How I can do this?

Code of my Activity:

```cs
private void ParseAndDisplay(JsonValue json)
{
    TextView productname = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.posttitle);
    TextView content = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.postcontent);
    TextView price = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.price);
    TextView weight = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.weight);
    ImageView imagen = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.image1);
    JsonValue firstitem = json[4];


    productname.Text = firstitem["post_title"];
    content.Text = firstitem["post_excerpt"];
    price.Text = firstitem["price"] + " грн";
    weight.Text = firstitem["weight"] + "г";
    var imageBitmap2 = GetImageBitmapFromUrl(firstitem["img_url"]);
    imagen.SetImageBitmap(imageBitmap2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use *int.Parse()*.
But I guess for the price you need the decimal type.

```
//convert the price to decimal
var priceValue = decimal.Parse(firstitem["price"]);
//then increase the price
priceValue += 1M;
//then update the UI
price.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00} грн", priceValue);
```

Comment: Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string' 


have this

Comment: are you having that at the line *var price = int.Parse(firstitem["price"]);*? If you got the error is because it's already an int, so you don't need int.Parse() :)

Comment: "price":"39.00"

it in json, as i understand it is string

Comment: I guess the problem is when you need to convert it back to string for the UI. I've rewritten the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95928/discussion-between-eugene-and-alefranz).

Answer (score 0):

When we are talking about about money  & you need to display money according to locale($,Rupee,Pound etc) you should use BigDecimal Class.

for example if you are in india you would be representing money using this class

```
public class Money {

    private static final Currency INR = Currency.getInstance(new Locale("en",
            "in"));
    private static final RoundingMode DEFAULT_ROUNDING = RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN;

    private BigDecimal amount;
    private Currency currency;

    public static Money rupees(BigDecimal amount) {
        return new Money(amount, INR);
    }

    Money(BigDecimal amount, Currency currency) {
        this(amount, currency, DEFAULT_ROUNDING);
    }

    Money(BigDecimal amount, Currency currency, RoundingMode rounding) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.currency = currency;

        this.amount = amount.setScale(currency.getDefaultFractionDigits(),
                rounding);
    }

    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public Currency getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getCurrency().getSymbol() + " " + getAmount();
    }

    public String toString(Locale locale) {
        return getCurrency().getSymbol(locale) + " " + getAmount();
    }
}
```

it will round off values to 2 decimal places and all calucation will be done with precision at scientific label.

To can display money on UI using above class like this it will add rupee symbol automatically :-

```
((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.price))
                .setText(Money.rupees(
                        BigDecimal.valueOf(Long.valueOf(GlobaDataHolder
                                .getGlobaDataHolder().getProductMap()
                                .get(productCategoryNumber)
                                .get(productNumber).getSellMRP())))
                        .toString());
```

To update checkout price use this method :-

```
public void updateCheckOutAmount(BigDecimal amount, boolean increment) {

//update global value of checkout amount
        if (increment) {
            checkoutAmount = checkoutAmount.add(amount);
        } else {
            if (checkoutAmount.signum() == 1)
                checkoutAmount = checkoutAmount.subtract(amount);
        }

//update displayed checkout amount on UI
        checkOutAmountTextView.setText(Money.rupees(checkoutAmount).toString());

    }
```